# Would sailing plankton be viable?

Tags: xenobiology, sea-creatures

I have made an alien world in which it seems like nekton would be unviable due to the slowness of animal life. Therefore these animals would be restricted to plankton (and slow plankton at that) and benthos

However, the absence of nekton would open up opportunities for plankters

Would it be realistically plausible for a planktonic species to be able to 'sail' on the ocean's flows, so that it could travel up or across a current like sailboats in wind?

This seems like it would certainly be useful, if possible, as it would make these beings far more maneuverable in the water, and make escaping or catching predators/prey much easier

Comment: I'm a bit confused. what organisms are you looking to test the viability of? Slow plants or slow animals? Plenty of sponges and corals feed off plankton all ready.  Jellyfish can gather food pretty passively, and they are considered planktonic. Sounds like jellyfish paradise. Portuguese man o' war?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sailing works through the addition of vectors, the wind versus the force on the keel down in the water.

Your plankton would drift with whatever current they're in, moving in just that direction, unless....

They can either swim - That's out.

They can sail by sticking a fin above water into the wind and a keel below to steer.

They move up or down by changing their buoyancy so that they arrive at a level in the water where the current is in the direction they want to go in.

Not a lot of use for pursuit-hunting, or frantic escape from predators, but a relatively energy-cheep way of migrating.

Comment: Not much controlled sailing, tho'. If the water current and the wind are in different directions (as in "travel up or across a current"), the [wind waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_wave) will negate the effect of the sail, in all but the times when the sail sticks above the  height of the wave - which may paradoxically make slow winds more effective for their controlled sailing. Unless, that is, the plankton grow tall sails.

Answer (score 2):

## Siphonophore paradise:

Such organisms already exist. The [jellyfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jellyfish) and [siphonophores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphonophorae) like the [Portuguese man o' war](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/portuguese-man-o-war.html)  are animals that already are planktonic low-motility predators drifting in the oceans and feeding off whatever they can get. The Man o; war already uses the wind to aid locomotion while feeding off of prey animals.

If your world lacks large highly motile prey, then the fishing strategy of these species would need to change. They functionally might need to be more like floating sponges or corals, picking off the innumerable smaller prey as the wind drags them through the waters. Or, they might need to employ a more net-like collector and 'clear' a small area of water of food as they move along.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### I propose the evolution of the spinnaker.

In early stages of the evolution, just a lightweight agglomeration of globular, gas filled formation, connected to a long, fibrous appendage. In late stages of evolution, it may get to a membranous appearance, which allow a certain degree of controlled orientation relative to the wind direction.

The organ may be coupled with reproductive functions as well, detaching (by wear off and/or drying out) the "lines" and continue flying with the wind and carrying the eggs to longer distances, in areals that are better suited for the spawn (shallower water or colder more oxygenated waters, make your choice).
Constant tugging and the vibrations produced by the wind may even be "engineered" to count as an orgasmic experience to favor the evolutionary selection, "tangling kite lines" is an opportunity for genetic material exchange.

The deployment of the spinnaker is a matter of chance, the spinnaker lines won't support much of a lifting force *on their own*, so it will necessary happen in quite choppy waters, with high winds, *especially winds going across or against the water currents*; in such conditions, the waves are usually of short wavelength, low amplitude, with quite cusp-like crests
[image]
Possibly, existence of seasonal weather patterns constant over long ages could favor the evolution of the spinnaker.